# CEF browser can't find Address property

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I am using CEFsharp browser version 69  in my winforms solution, trying to get URL address but I can't find address property, or GETURL method.

is there any alternative to get loaded URL address?

```
   chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://ourcodeworld.com");
            // Add it to the form and fill it to the form window.
            chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            chromeBrowser.LoadingStateChanged += ChromeBrowser_LoadingStateChanged;
            CEFbrowsercontainer.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
```

Comment: http://cefsharp.github.io/api/67.0.0/html/P_CefSharp_WinForms_ChromiumWebBrowser_Address.htm

Comment: Already solved !

Comment: I'm simply pointing out there is an Address property

Answer (score 0):

Just found URL address in another CEFSharp Event !

```
 private void ChromeBrowser_AddressChanged(object sender, AddressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        chromecurrentURL = e.Address;
    }
```